# Show all the axis labels even if blank

Tags: powerbi, dax

Imagine that I have a data like this:

[image]

Then I create two differnt graphs, filtering the sum of sales in one graph with "Category=A" and the same in the other one

[image]

Now I need that in the two graphs appears all the columns even if there is no data:

[image]

I have tried adding the measure

```
Include_All = CALCULATE(SUM(Tabla[Sales]),ALL(Tabla))
```

For add the measure as filter-page, but without results. What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any calendar table? If yes, use Date from the calendar date.

Comment: It would be the ideal,  the problem is that I have custom columns like ("Q7W4") so I need to use "categories".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new table like **all_dates** with all date available as shown below-

[image]

Now establish relation between your data table and new table using the column **Date**. Finally create the chart using **Date** column from the new table **all_dates** and select option **Show item with no data** as shown below-

[image]

Output will be something like below-

[image]

Comment: Looks Good, but what If I have a lot of categories and I want to specify which should be added for filter the "calendar"? That's why I tried to do it with a calculate, can you at least explain me why my calculate is not working?, anyway I give you the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: in your table, when you are filtering for category A,  there is no row with date 4 or 5 or 6 remains. So where from the chart will generate bar (even blank) for those dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this code :

```
Include_All = CALCULATE(SUM(Tabla[Sales]),ALL(Tabla)) + 0
```